# Why won't my string travel correctly through sockets?

Tags: java, android, sockets

```
05-16 14:29:16.935: W/System.err(20981): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
    unable to parse '��������������������' as integer
```

This is pretty much the error message my Android app shows when it's supposed to receive a 10-byte long string (which is shown as 20 different bytes in the error message.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

^^ I added UTF-8.

```
String count = String.format("%10s", 
        (new Integer(result.length())).toString()).replace(" ", "0");
```

This is how I obtain the string that I send, and it's working fine as it shows up correctly on the PC side log.

However, on the Android side, it's not received correctly.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.allocate(1024*1024);
in.read(buf);
char[] buffer = new char[10];
buf.get(buffer, 0, 10);
cont = Integer.parseInt(new String(buffer));
```

This is how I obtain the string back, and it doesn't seem to work correctly. Could someone with more experience help me understand why doesn't this work?

Comment: Are you encoding and decoding the string using the same Character set on both sides?

Comment: Could it be some encoding problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't edited anything related to encodings on either side.

Comment: I added UTF-8, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Java String's are Unicode, 2-byte per char affairs.  That's good to know.

You should probably tell the streams how the Strings are encoded.  UTF-8 is my recommendation.

I'd recommend that you forget about the number parsing bit for a while and just see if you can understand what's being sent back and forth.  The exception with the unreadable characters isn't useful.

Reduce your problem to a simple send and receive and log what is received.  Visibility and transparency are your friends here.  It's hard to see what is required until you know what you're getting.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm using BufferedWriter and BufferedReader for communication.

Comment: Specify the encoding in the Constructor...? Alternatively you could just send a byte[] which is optionally the hash of the string then the opposing side doesn't need to worry and encoding plays less of a role...

Comment: I added UTF-8, same result. :(